# jQuery and/or button tag pops browser to top of page on mobile - not desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've researched this issue, but have not come across an answer. A dice roller app I'm working on is fine on Desktop, but on Mobile, tapping on the red and green dice buttons cause the browser to immediately jump to the top of the page. When you scroll back down you see the desired set of dice have rolled, though. So I think it's an issue between my jQuery talking to my HTML/CSS. Could anyone spare a minute and take a look at what I'm doing wrong for Mobile? Thanks!

Full application at
https://codepen.io/ohBretterson/pen/aqZqZO?editors=1010

```
shootImg = new Array(
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_1.jpg", //Crosshair 1
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_2.jpg", //Crosshair 2
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_3.jpg", //Crosshair 3
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_question.jpg", //Question Mark
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_x.jpg", //Big X
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_crosshair.jpg" //Crosshair
);

meleeImg = new Array(
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_bloodaxe.jpg", //Blood Axe
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_fullaxe.jpg", //Solid Axe
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_hollowaxe.jpg", //Hollow Axe
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_questionmark.jpg", //Question Mark
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_shield.jpg", //Shield
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_x.jpg" //X
);

defenseImg = new Array(
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_ax.jpg", //Axe
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_ax.jpg", //Axe x2
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_questionmark.jpg", //Question Mark
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_shield.jpg", //Shield
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_shield.jpg", //Shield x2
  "http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_x.jpg" //X
);

//Shooting Dice Set

//Shooting: Tap die
$(".shooting").click(function() {
  var img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);
});

//Shooting: Roll first die
$(".oneDie").click(function() {
  var img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $(".shooting").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".shooting:first")
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".dice:first").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);
});

//Shooting: Roll 2 dice
$(".twoDie").click(function() {
  $(".shooting").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".shooting")
    .slice(0,2)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:first").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Shooting: Roll 3 dice
$(".threeDie").click(function() {
  $(".shooting").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".shooting")
    .slice(0,3)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:first").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
        img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Shooting: Roll 4 dice
$(".fourDie").click(function() {
  $(".shooting").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".shooting")
    .slice(0,4)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:first").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
        img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
     img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Shooting: Roll 5 dice
$(".fiveDie").click(function() {
  $(".shooting").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".shooting")
    .slice(0,5)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:first").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
        img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
     img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".shooting:eq(4)").css("background-image", "url(" + shootImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Shooting: Reset shooting die
$(".resetShooting").click(function() {
  $(".shooting")
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect")
    .delay(100)
    .queue(function() {
      $(this)
        .css(
          "background-image",
          "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/shootingdice_default.jpg)"
        )
        .dequeue();
    });
});

// Melee Dice Set

//Melee: Tap die
$(".melee").click(function() {
  var img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);
});

//Melee: Roll first die
$(".meOneDie").click(function() {
  var img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee:first")
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);
});

//Melee: Roll 2 dice
$(".meTwoDie").click(function() {
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,2)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 3 dice
$(".meThreeDie").click(function() {
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,3)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 4 dice
$(".meFourDie").click(function() {
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,4)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 5 dice
$(".meFiveDie").click(function() {
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,5)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(4)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 6 dice
$(".meSixDie").click(function() {
   $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,6)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(4)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(5)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 7 dice
$(".meSevenDie").click(function() {
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,7)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(4)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(5)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(6)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 8 dice
$(".meEightDie").click(function() {
   $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,8)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(4)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(5)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(6)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(7)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Roll 9 dice
$(".meNineDie").click(function() {
  $(".melee").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".melee")
    .slice(0,9)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:first").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(2)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(3)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(4)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(5)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(6)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(7)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".melee:eq(8)").css("background-image", "url(" + meleeImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Melee: Reset shooting die
$(".meReset").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".melee")
    .removeClass("spinEffect")

    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect")
    .delay(100)
    .queue(function() {
      $(this)
        .css(
          "background-image",
          "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/meleedice_default.jpg)"
        )
        .dequeue();
    });
});

// Defense Die Set

//Defense: Tap die
$(".defense").click(function() {
 var img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.css("background-image", "url(" + defenseImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);
});

//Defense: Roll first die
$(".defOneDie").click(function() {
   var img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $(".defense").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".defense:first")
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".defense:first").css("background-image", "url(" + defenseImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);
});

//Defense: Roll 2 dice
$(".defTwoDie").click(function() {
   $(".defense").css(
    "background-image",
    "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_default.jpg)"
  );
  $(".defense")
    .slice(0,2)
    .removeClass("spinEffect")
    .css(
      "background-image",
      "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_default.jpg)"
    )
    .fadeOut(150)
    .fadeIn(150)
    .addClass("spinEffect");
  setTimeout(function() {
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".defense:first").css("background-image", "url(" + defenseImg[img] + ")");
    img = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(".defense:eq(1)").css("background-image", "url(" + defenseImg[img] + ")");
  }, 340);

});

//Defense: Reset shooting die
$(".resetDefense").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".defense")
    .removeClass("spinEffect")

    .fadeOut("fast")
    .fadeIn("fast")
    .addClass("spinEffect")
    .delay(100)
    .queue(function() {
      $(this)
        .css(
          "background-image",
          "url(http://brettthurston.com/img/ph/defensedice_default.jpg)"
        )
        .dequeue();
    });
});
```

Comment: which mobile device are you using ? i can't see the problem on my nexus 6p/chrome, on codepen full screen

Comment: iPhone 6, Chrome and Safari. thanks for looking!

Comment: ok, i can confirm the behaviour. 100% on the green buttons, but not always on orange, very strange.  buttons will do the same stuff as the dice.

Comment: I thought it may have had something to do with the fadeout() and fadein() on my classes, but have removed them to test and still same effect.

Comment: What's weird is, the blue dice work flawlessly, tapping them individually or their button sets.

Comment: to test the blue dice you could add a padding top 100vh or something to move them out of view and then check if it moves up

Comment: Good call, I actually thought about testing the blues out like that over lunch. Sure enough, the blue dice go to top of page, after pushing them down 50vh. I wonder if it's the button tags and some default href behavior....

Comment: I'll leave this up for posterity sake, but I exported my code from CodePen and uploaded it to my domain - and everything works on Mobile as intended. So I'm assuming it's something going on with iPhone/CodePen/jQuery....

http://brettthurston.com/roller

Comment: well i saw something on codepen on iOS, the on screen keyboard opend a few time, but i was not sure if that was the problem because i used browserstack to emulate an iphone 6s, might be the problem, not sure tho